# Checkbox initial state when sharing form between new/edit views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to reuse code in a form between an edit and a new view. In the New view, I'd like the checkbox to be checked by default. In the edit view I'd like it to reflect the current state of the object. What's the best way to share this info? The code below is what I want for "new" but for edit I don't want it hard-coded to "**checked: true"**.

```
<div class="row">
    <%= form_for @producer_type do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :enabled %>
        <%= f.check_box :enabled, {checked: true} %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `:producer_type`? Is there a reason you're not using `form_for @producer_type` like usually done.

Comment: Probably my own fault, for something new wouldn't @producer_type be nil? NM - I see the right way, fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass an object from the controller to the form.

```
def new
  @producer_type = ProducerType.new(enabled: true)
end

def edit
  @producer_type = ProduceType.find(params[:id])
end
```

And use that in the form, Rails automatically checks it if enabled is true

```
<%= form_for @producer_type do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :enabled %>
```

Comment: Wouldn't I want it backwards from that?

Comment: Backwards, what do you mean?

Comment: Wouldn't I want enabled: true set for New? For edit I want the object's current state, unmodified.I think I know what I need, let me try it and reply in a few min.

Comment: This is what I need:     def new @producer_type = ProducerType.new(enabled: true) end  for edit, the original code (which is a lookup) is right.

Comment: I edited it, I was just showing the structure of what was needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `true` with `current_page?(action: 'edit')`

See [ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) for more on the current_page methods.

And I don't think you need the curly braces because the hash is at the end of a parameter list.

Comment: I tried: <%= f.check_box :enabled, checked: current_page?(action: 'edit') %>  - it seems to still be always checked. And thinking about that won't it just default it to false in edit and true in new?